# Is it possible to get information about all apps installed on iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to get the information (app icon, app name, app location) about all apps that have been installed on iPhone/iPod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a way to check if an application is installed or not, however, it does violate the Sandbox rules and Apple *may reject your app for using this. But it has been done before by other Apps that are available in the App Store, so feel free to try it

Sometimes you may want to check if a specific app is installed on the device, in case you use custom URL schemes that require some other app to be installed (you could just gray out/disable some buttons then). Unfortunately, Apple apparently does not have any function that checks this for you, so I whipped one up. It does not enumerate every single app, instead it uses the MobileInstallation cache which is always up-to-date with SpringBoard and holds the Info dictionaries of all apps installed. Although you're not "supposed" to access the cache, it's readable by App Store apps. Here is my code which at least works perfectly fine with the Simulator 2.2.1:
Code:

```
// Declaration
BOOL APCheckIfAppInstalled(NSString *bundleIdentifier); // Bundle identifier (eg. com.apple.mobilesafari) used to track apps

// Implementation

BOOL APCheckIfAppInstalled(NSString *bundleIdentifier)
{
    static NSString *const cacheFileName = @"com.apple.mobile.installation.plist";
    NSString *relativeCachePath = [[@"Library" stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"Caches"] stringByAppendingPathComponent: cacheFileName];
    NSDictionary *cacheDict = nil;
    NSString *path = nil;
    // Loop through all possible paths the cache could be in
    for (short i = 0; 1; i++)
    {

        switch (i) {
    case 0: // Jailbroken apps will find the cache here; their home directory is /var/mobile
        path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
        break;
    case 1: // App Store apps and Simulator will find the cache here; home (/var/mobile/) is 2 directories above sandbox folder
        path = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"../.."] stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
        break;
    case 2: // If the app is anywhere else, default to hardcoded /var/mobile/
        path = [@"/var/mobile" stringByAppendingPathComponent: relativeCachePath];
        break;
    default: // Cache not found (loop not broken)
        return NO;
        break; }

        BOOL isDir = NO;
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: path isDirectory: &isDir] && !isDir) // Ensure that file exists
            cacheDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: path];

        if (cacheDict) // If cache is loaded, then break the loop. If the loop is not "broken," it will return NO later (default: case)
            break;
    }

    NSDictionary *system = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"System"]; // First check all system (jailbroken) apps
    if ([system objectForKey: bundleIdentifier]) return YES;
    NSDictionary *user = [cacheDict objectForKey: @"User"]; // Then all the user (App Store /var/mobile/Applications) apps
    if ([user objectForKey: bundleIdentifier]) return YES;

    // If nothing returned YES already, we'll return NO now
    return NO;
}
```

Here is an example of this, assuming that your app is named "yourselfmadeapp" and is an app in the app store. 
Code:

```
NSArray *bundles2Check = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"com.apple.mobilesafari", @"com.yourcompany.yourselfmadeapp", @"com.blahblah.nonexistent", nil];
for (NSString *identifier in bundles2Check)
    if (APCheckIfAppInstalled(identifier))
        NSLog(@"App installed: %@", identifier);
    else
        NSLog(@"App not installed: %@", identifier);
```

Log Output:
Code:

> 2009-01-30 12:19:20.250
>   SomeApp[266:20b] App installed:
>   com.apple.mobilesafari 2009-01-30
>   12:19:20.254 SomeApp[266:20b] App
>   installed:
>   com.yourcompany.yourselfmadeapp
>   2009-01-30 12:19:20.260
>   SomeApp[266:20b] App not installed:
>   com.blahblah.nonexistent

Try this out before using it, I think Apple changed where the MobileInstallation.plist is located and if you do change it, try it out on an actual device not the simulator. Good Luck!

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/37103-finding-out-what-apps-installed.html

**PK**

Comment: This post is more than 2 years old ,you didn't think it would work right out of the bat with iOS 6 did you?
Also, explain what is not working, simply saying it's not working properly is not enough to help you.

Comment: Pavan, do you know of any apps on app store that use this? Thanks!

Comment: Not that I can think of; but if any application is interested to know whether a specific application is installed on a user's iDevice, the best way to go about doing that is to use the `iPhone URL schemes` and you can do a test if the application is installed by doing something like this: `if ([ourApplication canOpenURL:@"fb://"]) { NSLog(@"facebook installed");};` etc. That will let you know whether facebook is installed.

Comment: for me on iOS7 jailbroken all path return NO why?How can I fix that plz ?I need that urgency

Comment: ion iOS8 the com.apple.mobile.installation.plist is deleted with what it's replaced please?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get installed applications in iPhone is just call:

```
NSString *rootAppPath = @"/Applications";
NSArray *listApp = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:rootAppPath error:nil];
```

You can access then in each application to read their dictionary Info.plist to know more about these applications.

**UPDATE:** Obviously, this method does not work anymore (for iOS8) cause our application does not have permission to view the content of /Applications

Comment: There is no private API so it must be accepted in the App Store.

Comment: This returns *a* list of apps, not the correct one.  On the Sim, it returns the apps on the host machine, on real hardware, it looks like a list of the default apps.

Comment: This returns the list of default apps not the apps installed via app store.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this when the device is Jailbroken, so that you can reach out of the sandBox.
You can get the information you want by analyzing Info.plist in every *.app which is located at every path "/var/mobile/Applications/", such as  "/var/mobile/Applications/*/*.app/Info.plist"
Here is my code.

```
- (void)scan
{

    NSString *pathOfApplications = @"/var/mobile/Applications";

    NSLog(@"scan begin");

    // all applications
    NSArray *arrayOfApplications = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathOfApplications error:nil];
    for (NSString *applicationDir in arrayOfApplications) {
        // path of an application
        NSString *pathOfApplication = [pathOfApplications stringByAppendingPathComponent:applicationDir];
        NSArray *arrayOfSubApplication = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathOfApplication error:nil];
        // seek for *.app
        for (NSString *applicationSubDir in arrayOfSubApplication) {
            if ([applicationSubDir hasSuffix:@".app"]) {// *.app
                NSString *path = [pathOfApplication stringByAppendingPathComponent:applicationSubDir];

                path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];

                // so you get the Info.plist in the dict
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
                // code to analyzing the dict.
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"scan end");
}
```

Here is sample content of an Info.plist. So, get values for any key you care about.

```
{
BuildMachineOSBuild = 11G63;
CFBundleDevelopmentRegion = "zh_CN";
CFBundleDisplayName = "\U4e50\U89c6\U5f71\U89c6HD";
CFBundleExecutable = LetvIpadClient;
CFBundleIconFile = "icon.png";
CFBundleIconFiles =     (
    "icon.png",
    "icon@2x.png"
);
CFBundleIdentifier = "com.letv.ipad.hdclient";
CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion = "6.0";
CFBundleName = LetvIpadClient;
CFBundlePackageType = APPL;
CFBundleResourceSpecification = "ResourceRules.plist";
CFBundleShortVersionString = "3.1";
CFBundleSignature = "????";
CFBundleSupportedPlatforms =     (
    iPhoneOS
);
CFBundleURLTypes =     (
            {
        CFBundleURLName = "m.letv.com";
        CFBundleURLSchemes =             (
            letvIPad
        );
    }
);
CFBundleVersion = "3.1";
DTCompiler = "com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42";
DTPlatformBuild = 10A403;
DTPlatformName = iphoneos;
DTPlatformVersion = "6.0";
DTSDKBuild = 10A403;
DTSDKName = "iphoneos6.0";
DTXcode = 0450;
DTXcodeBuild = 4G182;
LSRequiresIPhoneOS = 0;
MinimumOSVersion = "4.3";
UIDeviceFamily =     (
    2
);
"UILaunchImageFile~ipad" =     (
    "Default.png",
    "Default@2x.png"
);
UIPrerenderedIcon = 1;
UIStatusBarHidden = 1;
UISupportedInterfaceOrientations =     (
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,
    UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
);
"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad" =     (
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight,
    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it will work even with non-jailbroken devices

```
#include <objc/runtime.h>
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
SEL selector=NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
NSObject* workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];

SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
NSLog(@"apps: %@", [workspace performSelector:selectorALL]);
```