# How to determine, whether an iphone app (previous/next version) is existed in our device or not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, iphone-sdk-3.0, app-store

- I Have an app with 2 versions....  **iPaint1** (*`FreeVersion`*) & **iPaint2**(*`Paid Version`*)

iPaint 2 has extra features along with the features of iPaint1..

- if user have iPaint1 & also if he installed Paint2.

Now we need to display An alert when user launch/uses paint2. Alert will be pop up as

**`"You already have all features of paint1 in this 2nd version, Delete Paint1 to free space"`**

only if iPain1 is existed in our device, otherwise no need of alert How is it possible.

(I guess we may achieve this this using AppStore ID & Bundle Identifier but not sure and don't know the process)

Thanks in advance

---

***But It is works on simulator but not in iPod***

---

Answer :

Finally i Got solution in @MDT 's answer. thank u @MDT and others as well.

Thank you for your quick response.. This link is useful for this question.

[Is it possible to get information about all apps installed on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone/3878220#3878220)

and in

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/22289-possible-retrieve-these-information.html#post101753

***But It is works on simulator but not in iPod*** any advice pls.

Comment: I haven't seen any other apps that do this and I would suggest that you leave it to the user to decide whether to delete your previous version or not.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick response.. This link is useful for this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone/3878220#3878220

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Without jailbreaking, there is no way for an app to directly get a
> list of all installed apps on an iOS device.

http://www.quora.com/An-iOS-App-how-to-find-all-other-application-on-the-iPhone

Your best alternative may to be use of custom URL schemes. With these you can implement a link in your free app that opens the paid one if it is installed.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.. This link is useful for this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone/3878220#3878220

Comment: That is because it's a simulator, not an emulator. The simulator is pretty good, but doesn't not perfectly demonstrate the devices actually functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom URL scheme. Provide some custom URL to free App. Now on the starting of paid App, check if it can responds to the custom URL of your free App. If it can, there exists a free version on the device and display the message to remove it.

Comment: please, let me clarify it how can we check with this custom URL

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.. This link is useful for this question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone/3878220#3878220