# iphone app is existed in our device or not? is not working on iPod / iPhone devies, works only on simulator.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, app-store, ios-simulator

to know which Apps are installed on a given device i have followed the way as follows.

[How to determine, whether an iphone app (previous/next version) is existed in our device or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100713/how-to-determine-whether-an-iphone-app-previous-next-version-is-existed-in-ou)

This can find the applications (user's apps & system apps) installed in ***SIMULATOR*** perfectly.

***But fail to find in my original device iPod / iPhone.***

why and how to rectifie it for Devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to achieve this on **non-jailbroken device**.

There is a way (a workaround really) to detect your own applications if they register `custom url`: method is described here: [How To Detect Installed iOS Apps](http://amitay.us/blog/files/how_to_detect_installed_ios_apps.php)

EDIT: if you decide to go this way you can learn how to register custom URL here:

[Registering Custom URL Schemes](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

[Objective-C: Custom URL Schemes](http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html)

**EDIT**: after additional information: you want to check if your application is installed and this application registered `paintplus` URL scheme

You can use this method (in your other application) to check if `paintplus` is installed or not:

```
- (BOOL) paintplusInstalledOnThisDevice {

  UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];  
  NSURL *paintplusURL = [NSURL URLWithString: @"paintplus://"];
  return [app canOpenURL: paintplusURL];
}
```

Comment: There is no description of regestering custom url in that link.

Comment: ok registered url. after that how can we found wether A PERTICULER application is installed or not or list of installed apps.

Comment: @Ranga: there's a link on the bottom: http://amitay.us/ihasapp/index.php What you do is you that with one of your apps (appA) you register an URL and with your other app (appB) you can check if this URL is registered on that device - that would mean that the appA is installed

Comment: Hai rokj **iHasApp** example is working in device, but it shows only 3 applications out of bundle of apps in my ipod. mainly it doesn't show the application, what i required actually. what to do show my app also... ***I have Registered URL handle  for the my required application 'paintplus' . I added URL types in info.plist in that I added URL identifier 'com.rapid.paintplus' and URL scheme 'paintplus'. But not found the paintplus app in the installed apps list.***

Comment: please help me to display my app in applist in iHasApp Examples table..
bundle of thanks in advance,

Comment: @Ranga: hi, i'm at windows computer now, but i'll test this as soon as i can

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9988/discussion-between-ranga-and-rokjarc)

Comment: @Ranga: i added some code that should do the trick for you. I'm not able to test this at the moment but you can :) hope it works

Comment: You Rocks rokj. Thank you very much, it's working it was very very help ful to me,