# Get list of icons for all installed apps

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an application that need all installed application list with their icons i can get the application list but can't getting their icons. Is there any way to access the icons of installed application ??

Comment: Curious, how are you getting the application list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614691/finding-list-of-installed-apps-on-iphone

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone

Comment: Gotcha, looks like that method validates sandbox rules. Accessing the icons would do the same and would probably crash if you tried to read files in other application's bundles. In short, no, there is no way to get app icons for an app store app. Jailbreaking would be a different ball of wax.

Comment: Using this i can get the icon name but that can't load in to imageView to load in to imageView i need a path for that icon and all icon of    apps is stored in to .app file so this can't working...

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest and most valid way to do this, would be fetching the icons from the web.** One of the best resources could be the **iTunes App Store** available online. You can use the search or a bundle ID to get the application and then parse out the icon.

*See this document for more information:*

http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

You can then use `SDWebImage` to display the icons or any other library to load the icon to local database.

**This way is also valid for App Store.**