# List all Info.plist files on iPhone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, info.plist

Is there any way in ios world to list all installed apps Info.plist files through objective-c? If possible how to read attributes of each Info.plist file? I used below code but it is displaying only scan begin and scan end.

```
 - (void)scan
   {
    NSString *pathOfApplications = @"/var/mobile/Applications";

    NSLog(@"scan begin");

    // all applications
    NSArray *arrayOfApplications = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathOfApplications error:nil];
    for (NSString *applicationDir in arrayOfApplications) {
        // path of an application
        NSString *pathOfApplication = [pathOfApplications stringByAppendingPathComponent:applicationDir];
        NSArray *arrayOfSubApplication = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathOfApplication error:nil];
        // seek for *.app
        for (NSString *applicationSubDir in arrayOfSubApplication) {
            if ([applicationSubDir hasSuffix:@".app"]) {// *.app
                NSString *path = [pathOfApplication stringByAppendingPathComponent:applicationSubDir];

                path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Info.plist"];

                // so you get the Info.plist in the dict
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
                // code to analyzing the dict.
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"scan end");
   }
```

source: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878197/is-it-possible-to-get-information-about-all-apps-installed-on-iphone)

Comment: No this is not possible

Comment: @msk Why? What is the reason for it?

Comment: Every application is sandboxed in iOS. No app can access any other app's sandbox region. May be possible if iOS is jail broken.

Comment: As you source states, it's only possible if the device is Jailbroken (if at all). Also, you will be rejected from the AppStore if your app reaches out of the sandbox.

Comment: @DanielRinser Any private API to get Info.plist files. I dont want my app in appstore

Comment: No, it's not possible on non-jailbroken phones. iOS completely separates the apps' file systems. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @DanielRinser Trying to list all installed apps on iphone

Comment: AFAIK, the best you can do on non-jailbroken devices is to scan for registered URL schemes. But this will require a mapping between URL scheme and app, and obviously only gives you the apps that have a custom URL scheme registered.